# Cannot copy text from tmux integrated terminal in update 1.82.2

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, zsh, tmux, vscode-remote

I solved this issue of copying text from tmux window inside Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal [by holding Option key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275178/copy-text-from-tmux-inside-vscode) but with the latest upgrade to 1.82.2 I am not able to copy the text from tmux window anymore.

I tried changing several settings related to terminal, tried holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> but nothing worked. Is there any solutions to this?

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Please post this at i.e. [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

If yours was the same problem I had, I had to turn on this setting: "Terminal > Integrated > Mac Option Click Forces Selection"

[image: Mac Option Click Forces Selection option in VS Code]

VS Code 1.84.2

Credit: https://superuser.com/questions/1688563/how-to-copy-with-the-mouse-from-tmux-in-vs-code-to-the-osx-clipboard